# change option values based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 1 requirement I'm trying to achieve.

1) hide/unhide selection tag based on which radio button is selected

CodePen: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/GizmoJ/pen/gGjZjo)

The user should ONLY be able to 'check' the unchecked radio button. 
E.g. If radio button A is 'checked', radio button B can be checked but not button A. vice versa.

```
$('#award, #year').click(function(){
// $('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').prop('checked', false);
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {

if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  $('#awardOptions').toggleClass('hide');
  $('#yearOptions').toggleClass('hide'); 
}else{
  $(this).prop('checked', false);
   $('#awardOptions').toggleClass('hide');
  $('#yearOptions').toggleClass('hide'); 
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `if` condition is being met, then your `else` condition is also being met. Considering you're toggling the visibility of the targets in both conditions, you're actually successfully showing the right element, then immediately hiding it again.

To resolve your problem, all you actually have to do is remove your `else` statement entirely. This can be seen **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/XeBGeY)**.

Also, you don't actually need to set the `checked` `prop` to `true` with `$(this).prop('checked', true)`, as it is **already** true (as the logic enters the `if($(this).is(':checked'))` conditional).

#### Update

The above causes an issue where clicking on the selected input still has the toggle.

This can be resolved by simply changing the logic to isolate the two behaviours entirely, then enforcing the visibility of the desired element, and invisibility of the other:

```
// Toggle award/year slider
$('#award').click(function(){
  $('#awardOptions').show();
  $('#yearOptions').hide(); 
});
$('#year').click(function(){
  $('#awardOptions').hide();
  $('#yearOptions').show(); 
});
```

This works because it functions regardless of the current state; the hiding and showing is explicit rather than based on a toggle.

The existing CodePen has been modified to include this, which again can be found **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/XeBGeY)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is what I ran into previously. The flaw is that if I click the Year or Award button twice after it is 'checked' it will change the selection tag which is an attribute I want disabled.

Comment: Yes. separating them into two click functions makes it simpler. I'll look at maybe making them 1 function but using a ternary

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for you:

```js
$('#award, #year').click(function(){
  if($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked')){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $('#awardOptions').addClass('hide');
    $('#yearOptions').addClass('hide'); 
    console.log("Add Class");
  }else{
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    $('#awardOptions').removeClass('hide');
    $('#yearOptions').removeClass('hide'); 
    console.log("Remove Class");
  }
});
```

You should remove each() function, because it calls twice.